# Relationships in SQL on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I haven't ever really used foreign keys in my databases, I have always just written code that would enforce things for me, but I'm looking towards shifting some of that logic to the database and learning more about foreign keys.

I currently have a database which has the table `Categories`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [CategoryID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentCategoryID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryStatus] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryTitle] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CategorySlug] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryThumbnail] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [CategoryHeaderImage] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [CategoryDescription] [text] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UI_Categories_Slug] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CategorySlug] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would like to create a foreign key that relates `ParentCategoryID` back up to `CategoryID`. When creating the FK, which would be the primary column, and which would be the foreign column in this instance?

Comment: 'I haven't ever really used foreign keys in my databases' - wow, +1 for a brave statement! And now do something about that quickly.

Comment: @Ozren in some shops foreign keys are prohibited because they "slow things down."

Comment: @AaronBertrand: there are two statements on this very page that are very amusing and I find them hard to believe; your true story and FK slowing things down :D

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić: always been a php/mysql developer from the mysql 3.x and php 3.x days, never brought myself to learn about anything that i didnt NEED with databases really. database design is the one area of programming that once i picked it up, i left it as it was mostly, now i am attempting to vastly advance my knowledge to catch up with the advancements i have learned in php, c#, c++, and everything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would think that `ParentCategoryID` would have to be `NULL`able (unless you want a top-level parent to point to itself, and that doesn't make much sense).

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Categories
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SelfParent
  FOREIGN KEY (ParentCategoryID)
  REFERENCES dbo.Categories(CategoryID);
```

*True story: at a job interview at Microsoft (several years ago), a SQL Server person told me that this wasn't possible.*

Comment: `ParentCategoryID` defaults to `0` (zero) rather than `NULL`. will accept as soon as i am able though. thanks

Comment: Then you can't have a foreign key because it either has to be NULL or a *valid* value. Since your IDENTITY column starts at 1, we can assume that CategoryID = 0 does not exist.